# Convert UTC timestamp to PST in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, typescript2.0

In my application, I am getting a finish timestamp data from server side which is in this format - `2021-02-19T06:30:58` . This is in UTC.

The requirement from client is to convert this timestamp in PST hours. The format should look like `Feb 19, 2021 06:30 AM` (Time should be converted to PST hours) . How to do this in Angular/Typescript.

For now this is how I am doing in my html code - `{{ (finishTimeStamp | date : 'MMM d, yyyy')}}` and it gives the result as `Feb 19, 2021`.

How can I include the time as well after converting it to PST hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
{{ (finishTimeStamp | date : 'MMM d, yyyy hh:mm a' : '-0800') }}
```

Comment: This is showing the result as Feb 19, 2021 06:30 AM, but its in UTC. We need to convert this to PST.

Comment: Works now. Confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add time manually using **getTime()**. which gets time in milliseconds.

1. **1 minute = 60000 milliseconds**
2. **60 minutes = 60x60000**
3. **5 hours = 300x60000**
4. and so on...

**Eg:**

```
curDate=new Date();

futDate=new Date(this.curDate.getTime()+330*60000);
```

This will add **5 hours 30 minutes** to current time.